# How to set individual fields permission on content type fields based on roles using field permssion

Tags: users, entities

I am using field permission module. I want some fields to be editable for other roles which I set using field permission module, but when I login as that user role I don't get the edit option on the node.

What I am actually trying to achieve is this:

1. I have created a content type with fields.
2. I want editor role users to submit pictures for that post.
3. They should not be able to edit other fields but just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field permissions do not add permissions, but only take permissions away.

If a user is not allowed to edit a node, giving him the permission to edit a field won't work. Instead you must give him permission to edit all nodes (of a certain type) and deny access to all field he may not edit. (and yes that can be a struggle if you add fields in the future)

Comment: **Thanks** This worked for me. Definitely i do understand you concern with regard to add new fields latter and give them permissions again. Anyways this worked for now. Thanks again